# No sound in second login, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-10.04, pulse-audio

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my system.
When I am logged on locally I have excellent sound.

If I make a second login as a different user 
`ssh -X other@localhost` 
that user cannot get audio.

When I try to run `mplayer` I get the error message

```
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
```

Should I ssh as the console-user, everything works fine.
I suspect that somehow I should enable pulseaudio for this second user, however I don't know how to do this.

/L

(If someone wonders why I do this, I am experimenting with having different account for dedicated tasks. Like banking, youtubeing, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, there are some pulseaudio settings in *Pulseaudio Preferences* that are needed. However that is not installed by default in Ubuntu 10.04.

```
 sudo apt-get install paprefs
 paprefs
```

(paprefs also available System -> Preferences -> Pulseaudio Preferences)

Enable "Network access to local sound devices".

/L

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I don't know about Ubuntu, but in Mandriva Linux there is a setting in the sound configuration called "Enable user switching for audio applications" which makes what you are asking for. Unfortunately I don't know how to set this in console or in Ubuntu.

You could also try to disable pulse and use only alsa and see if it's working that way.

Comment: Yes, I suspect there is something like that.   
I just cant find it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more ... I'm not a big fan of Ubuntu. However here are a few tips I found with google:
 - try looking for a setting with policykit
 - try disabling pulse and using ALSA which should have this setting enabled by default

Comment: Thanks for the help, it gave me an idea on which track to search along. /L